# How can I use the trend of a graph to plot the next point?

Tags: methodology, chemometrics

I created a hypothesis for a chemistry assignment and then conducted an experiment. The experiment resulted in a graph that had a downward trajectory. It looked like this:
[image: the graph]

I found the data points by calculating the averages of the temperature and reaction rates of certain reactants. Variable X and variable Y represent the average of the reaction time (y) and the temperature of the water (x) respectively.

Now I am required to find out the y-value of a point on the graph with 5 as the x-value. How could I find this point?

Comment: You are expected to extrapolate the data leftwards presumably with a line (or possibly a curve).  What have you tried?

Comment: Use the [FitPoly command](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/FitPoly_Command) in [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en)

Comment: The statistical standards of most instructional chemistry experiments are usually met by taking a ruler to the plot so it lies as close to the points as possible and reading the height of that ruler at the abscissa $x=5.$  To do that, you will have to zoom out a little bit so the horizontal axis includes $x=5.$